# When declaring variable is not completed, why compiler know its size?

Tags: c

After pointer `pa` declaring, right now,to use it in the function `malloc()`,

why compiler can know its size? And compiler how to parse under code:

```
int *pa = malloc(10 * sizeof *pa); // allocate an array of 10 int
```

and

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Node *next;  
}
```

`prev` and `next` is `struct Node *`, but now `struct Node` is undefined.

Why compiler is able to allocate enough size for `*prev`, `*next`?

Comment: because they are pointers. Compiler knows how much memory to allocate for pointers.

Comment: They're pointers - a varaible that holds the address of another.  The delivery address field on an online sales form is the same size no matter whether the delivery is to an economy apartment or a billionaire mansion.

Answer (score 2):

Because they are pointers. Compiler knows how much memory to allocate for pointers.

Comment: sir, you mean the pointer of all type is same size under one machine?so complier allocate the same size to all type pointer?

Comment: @linsir I think you're mixing up the _size of the pointer_ (usually 4 bytes on a 32 bit system and 8 bytes on a 64 bbit system) and the _size of the object the pointer points to_.

Comment: @linsir pointer size depends on different factors. But in general yes. You can check it by printing out `sizeof(int*)` and `sizeof(struct Node*)`

Comment: @linsir, generally, yes. The standard states that pointers to data types are the same size on a system. But pointer to a function does not need to be (though it's mostly same, except some architectures).

Answer (score 1):

In case of the structure declaration shown here, the member variables you are interested in are *pointer-to-some-type*.

For any given environment, a pointer (to type) holds a defined size. While allocating memory for a variable of the type, compiler need not know the actual size for the type, it just needs to know the size required for a pointer to that type and it knows that.

Comment: @StoryTeller agree. Let me edit the words.

Comment: @sorush-r in assembly, pointer is just a address, but it's casting is rely on another instruction

Answer (score 0):

Compiler does not allocate enough space for a `Node` structure, inside a `Node` structure. Though it does know how much a pointer needs, and allocates enough space for two pointers and in integer.